# Displaying the path to the file found by the recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion

I wrote a simple function to search for files on the computer. It works, everything is fine, but I can't understand 2 points, tell me, please.

1. Now I enter the file name separately via "name", but if I try to add name as one of the required parameters of the function (next to path) and specify it when calling the function, then for some reason the program stops giving results.
2. After the return is triggered, the function should stop working, but for some reason it continues to spin and fill the list with a million files even after it has already found the right one and return has worked. How else can it be stopped then?

```
import os

list1 = []
name = input()

def find(path, level=1):
    if name in os.listdir(path):
        return print(list1[-1])
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path+'\\'+i):
            list1.append(path + '\\' + i)
            find(path + '\\' + i, level + 1)

find("D:\\User")
```

Comment: Try adding `print(path)` to the top of your function.  You might find that something is coming back from `os.listdir` that you didn't account for.

Comment: what you think `return print()` does?

Answer (score 0):

For point 1: this is hard to debug without seeing your code as you describe. In theory it should work, but how you implement it might make a difference. For instance, how are you handling the `name` variable when you call `find` in the for loop?

For point 2: as you've prepared this as a recursive function, only the function instance that finds `name` actually hits the return function. All the other instances that don't find `name` won't complete until they've exhausted their for loops.

On another note, you seem to be writing code that can be more simply accomplished using the `glob` module. Try reading the [glob documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) and see if that might work for you.